# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ComponentBase' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: blazor

I encountered this error while writing some Blazor components and am confused as to why it is happening. The workaround seems to be to provide a class from a variable, but I am not sure why that works.

[image: Weird type error]

Comment: You ought to know by now: do not post code as images. They don't google well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are created, managed and destroyed by the `Renderer`.  You can't create them and pass them into the render process to get them rendered.

You're writing Razor code, which gets precompiled by the Razor compiler into a C# class inheriting from `ComponentBase`.

A `RenderFragment` is simply a delegate with the pattern

```cs
    void Method(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
```

The Renderer passes in a `RenderTreeBuilder` and the code within the method is run in the context of the owning component.

In your case the "compiled" code within the C# class looks something like this:

```cs
    private RenderFragment Pot10(int size)
    {
        return (__builder2) =>
        {
            __builder2.OpenElement(11, "div");
            __builder2.AddAttribute(12, "class", "pot-size");
            __builder2.AddContent(13, size);
            __builder2.CloseElement();
        };
    }
```

`__builder2` is a class level `RenderTreeBuilder` instance created during the Razor compilation process.

The Razor compiler is pretty good at interpreting various concoctions of C# and markup and turning it into `RenderTreeBuilder` code which is probably what you see as "weird conversions going on under the hood".